# RestKit and Restlet JSON key-value

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restlet

In `RestKit` for mapping a class to `JSON` key-value we use,

```
RKObjectMapping * userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];        
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"PrimaryKey" toAttribute:@"id"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:usereMapping forKeyPath:@"clientUser"];
```

However in android, if restlet is used, we just have to add `@JsonProperty("PrimaryKey"),` when declaring the variable in the class. And the Key value mapping is done.

Is there a simpler way for iOS restkit similar to `android restlet?`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in ios

```
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
[articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ 
        @"title": @"title",
        @"body": @"body",
        @"author": @"author",
        @"publication_date": @"publicationDate"
    }];
```

And

```
// Create our new Author mapping
RKObjectMapping* authorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Author class] ];
// NOTE: When your source and destination key paths are symmetrical, you can use addAttributesFromArray: as a shortcut instead of addAttributesFromDictionary:
[authorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name", @"email" ]];
```

[REFER HERE](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)